# Link to and play mp4 video in phonegap app on android

Tags: android, video, cordova

Im starting to loose my mind her.

Im building a VERY simple app.
All it needs to do, is show some information, an play some videos.

Everything works just great on iOS. I simply link to the video like this `<a href="video/afbryder.mp4"><span></span><img src="img/vidImg_afbryder.png" /></a>`, and it starts playing.

But on Android, its a totally deferent story. When i straigt-up link to the video like the ios version, nothing happens.

When i use this https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer, and my link looks like this
`<a href="javascript:window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/video/afbryder.mp4");"><span></span><img src="img/vidImg_afbryder.png" /></a>`, nothing happens.

All the videos ar contained locally in the app, as it needs to work offline.

Im building the app with HTML/CSS/JS in webstorm and then compiling it on build.phonegap.com/
Im not using x-code or anythin, just stright-up HTML/CSS/JS. i do have the config.xml file

Ive tried searching like a mad man, but still no luck. Can someone help me, or point me in the right direction.

P.S. This is my first app, and therefor my first encounter with phonegap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use any one plugin, you have to use a specific one for Android and one for iOS. After this, you need to compile using xcode or eclipse, for example. To use the plugin you mentioned, have a look on http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. everything i starting to fall in to place now :)